# Close vote review audit is broken - displays "on hold" while reviewing

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just reviewed this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2385381

But while reviewing, it already displays the "put on hold as not a real question" section, and it asked:

> Should this question be closed as: ?

So as it stands, the audits are broken, since we already know that the question is "on hold" while reviewing, and it is incredibly hard to miss the huge grey box at the bottom.

Another with screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Is this really a bug? I thought audits were meant to be obvious :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak That's a bit too hard to miss:) I can harvest these audits now, but I am too lazy to do that.

Comment: At this point, it's easy to write a _real_ review-bot. I assume this box has a nice ID the script could use :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Perhaps just search for [closed] and/or [on hold] will be enough for an useable bot :)

Comment: just came across this and was about to post a screenshot myself

Comment: I just got three of these today. Two were supposed to be closed, and one was a fake close that fooled me because of the first two...

Comment: @Neil so there exist fake closes? I've met five of them and all closed, but could this be a hideous way of auditing?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I guess I should have saved the link to the audit in question, but I'm sure it displayed that the question had already been closed.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I have since had one of each audit, but now I know what to expect, I passed them both appropriately.

Comment: The lack of a close reason may still be an audit bug though.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2442460 might be a fake close audit.

Comment: It was, someone else was given it 3 hours later (they left it open of course).

Comment: And I just got a correct audit, which I promptly failed. Sigh.