# This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle, except it wouldn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I tried to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17421839/560648) (#1) as a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797810/1369235) (#2), but SO told me:

[image: "This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle."]

If you want to stop me from creating dup chains then, well I disagree with that, but I can at least accept it.

But there's no *circle* here. No question is marked as a dup of #1 at present. At the very least, then, the message is incorrect.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: copy/paste fail; thanks hims!

Comment: Yes the same happened with me today on Meta when I voted a question as a duplicate of [my this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186757/187824) which is closed as a duplicate of [this **non-closed** question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185904/187824)

Comment: Looks like Jarrod was [too hungry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186745/circular-duplicate-link-allowed/186754#comment573239_186745) when fixing [related bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186754/152859)! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, > rev 2013.7.2.1156.

Comment: Oh I do love a version number in a bug report :) +1

Comment: aside: meta site footer says "rev 2013.7.2.1160" already - you guys don't mess around

Comment: I can confirm that, in the case of the questions in question [sic], this bug is fixed. Ta!

Comment: @Light yep, Meta revision appears to be different than the rest of the network - the devs are using Meta for tests many times before going network wide hence more revisions. :)