# Close Vote Queue: Duplicate question issue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

While reviewing a question in the close vote queue on Board Games I noticed an issue where a suggested duplicate was already closed as a duplicate of question I was reviewing.

What should happen if two questions get into the close vote queue to be closed as duplicates of each other?

This question was suggested to be a duplicate of [Circular duplicate link allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186745/circular-duplicate-link-allowed) but that is showing this as a fixed issue from 2013 (has status completed tag) and there appears to be something new that is allowing for questions to be suggested duplicates in circular logic again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular duplicate link allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186745/circular-duplicate-link-allowed)

Comment: Short answer: if one gets closed first, you won't be able to finish closing the other.

Comment: @muru In this case I was the final vote to leave it open and the review was completed. If the the votes would have attempted to close the question the votes would have failed?

Comment: You would get a message that looks somewhat like this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186981/270345

Comment: @muru from what I see in that question it should happen before the question is in the close vote queue not after. In this case shouldn't the second question to be suggested as a duplicate of the other been denied on the spot rather then waiting until others agree with the close votes?

Comment: From experience, the message comes only after one of the posts has been closed as a dupe of the other. I guess the rejection *could* be made whenever it's suggested, but I think this lets the community pick either way, instead of settling on the one that first got the close vote.

Comment: @muru What should be happening in my opinion is that once the first question is in the review queue to be closed as a duplicate the second one should not be allowed to be tagged as a duplicate of the first one. If the community thinks that the first question should stay open and the second one should be closed as a duplicate they should deal with the flags on the first question before working on the second.

Comment: I don't think it's that big a deal. As long as the system doesn't allow closing both questions as dupes of each other, it doesn't make much of a difference allowing both to be reviewed.

Comment: Maybe it's just a meta thing... but I see dupe chains here all the time. One question will be duped to another, which will be a dupe of a third...

Comment: @Catija: Dupe chains are fine, as long as they're acyclic (in the computer science sense); it's only when A points to B (directly or indirectly) which is also pointing to A (directly or indirectly) that you have problems.

Comment: @catija the issue here is question one was flagged as a dupe of question two which was already closed as a dupe of question one. Leaving it in a short circuit.

Comment: Hmm. I see, the bug here is that the first question should have been kicked off the review queue when the other got closed.